# Response.Redirect ReturnUrl

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to use Response.Redirect on an ASP.NET page that uses routing and membership -- in order to redirect non logged in users to the main page. This is a page that should sometimes be viewable to anonymous users based on content. When I redirect to the login page, the browser fills the returnurl with invalid content.

The question is how do I remove the ReturnURL before sending the user "off"? Or how do I fix it so that it includes the proper link?

The page is in a different directory. It redirects properly but sets the ReturnURL to an invalid path.

The ReturnUrl is just set to the folder. Not to the page with query params nor do the route.

UPDATE

Okay where is what it is doing

I have a folder Actions. I'm redirecting to Login.aspx. It redirects to login.aspx but then sets the returnurl to Actions/Login.aspx which is absolutely wrong.

It is wrong on 2 accounts:

1. The login.aspx doens't exist in the actions folder
2. It creates a recursive redirect

Update Fixed Partially

Okay, it was because I was in a different folder and not redirecting to the proper page.

I had "login.aspx" instead of "../login.aspx"

However, it is not setting the returnurl to the routed path. It is stripping the returnurl. I may have decided to do this as a design decision though, not 100% sure.

Comment: What is this invalid content? How have you implement the redirect? Is the route you are redirecting to OK with your routing rules? And of course, **what is your question**?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: @Oded there is really no code relevant. If you implement routing in an ASP.NET forms page, turn on authentication, add allow all users to a path that is a routed path, AND then try to redirect the user back to the login. You will see this.

Comment: @Oded 1 sec.. I will provide more details

Comment: I guess I just don't understand what is going on from your description. I don't know what the URL you are redirecting to is, what your routing looks like and what the invalid content is and where it shows up. And I can promise you that if I don't get it, others don't either.

Comment: OK. Can you post your redirect code? Or explain where you are setting the redirect to `Login.aspx`?

Answer (score 2):

I have not understood the nitty gritty of the issue you are facing, but I guess you might have missed to apply `Server.UrlEncode` to return url. Please have a look at what `Server.UrlEncode` does at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525738(v=vs.90).aspx

Below is the piece of code which shows how specify Return Url using `Server.UrlEncode`

```
Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl + "?ReturnUrl=" + 
Server.UrlEncode(Request.Url.ToString()))
```